# Each form control should have associated text issue for the input field with display:none

Tags: jsp, section508

In my jsp, i have one text field with `display:none style`. For the 508-Accessibility issues, i added one more hidden label for the text field.But still am getting the error on the text field like  **"Each form control should have associated text"**

Here is my code..

```
<label for="helper" style="visibility:hidden"></label>
<input type="text" style="display: none" id="helper" name="helper" title="helper" />
```

Comment: Well, there is no text in your label.

Comment: @JBNizet No.. Issue is for text field and not for the label. i just tried to add the label to resolve this issue..i mean when i remove the label then that time also,it will raise the issue.

Comment: OK, but have you tried with a non-empty label? What does your tool say about this error?

Comment: @JBNizet. Our text field also not shown in the UI. It is like hidden field to set some intermediate values.So, our label also should not contain any text. we just tried to add a label to fix this issue.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Your label is invisible anyway. So what's the problem in adding text inside. Or at least trying to do so and see if it fixes the issue?

Comment: @JBNizet. ok. Got it now..I will try it.Thanks!